# How to Get callback after Visual Studio Solution gets Build through VS SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I am using code written below..

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll"); // Saving all files before building

dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.ReBuildSolution"); // Buidling solution
```

I want to execute subsequent code statements only after successfull build of solution .
Is there any callback defined which notifies successful/unsuccessful build ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using an extension (add-in or package), don't use that way of getting the DTE instance, because Marshal.GetActiveObject(...) returns a running instance of DTE, and if you have two instances of VS open, you could get the wrong instance. The correct way is:

- For add-ins: the instance passed in the OnConnection method.
- For packages: see [HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/).

Second, see the article: [HOWTO: Performing some action before or after a build from a Visual Studio macro or add-in](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

The best approach is to use the [IVsBuildableProjectCfg.AdviseBuildStatusCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildableprojectcfg.advisebuildstatuscallback.aspx) method to get [IVsBuildStatusCallback.BuildEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildstatuscallback.buildend.aspx) called and check the fSuccess parameter.

Comment: thanks  @Carlos , I will try this approach , but msdn showing C++ syntax on these links , while I am writing in C#..